# Dual function space of Sobolev space $W^{1,p}​$.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, dual-spaces

The question is about the dual function space of Sobolev space $W^{1,p}​$.

Let $\Omega$ be a  bounded Lipchitz domain of $\mathbb{R}^3$. For purpose of simplicity of argument, domain $\Omega$ can be even selected as a cube.

Let p,q be the pair such that $1/p+1/q=1,q>3, 0<p<3/2$.

Given  $v \in W^{1,q}(\Omega) $, $v$ can be regarded a functional on $W^{1,p}$, i.e., $v\in {W^{-1,p}}$. Then, how to prove that there exists $C>0$ such that
$$
\|v\|_{{W^{-1,p}} } =
\sup_{0 \neq ||u||_{1,p} \leq 1} \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v  + uv ~\mbox{d}\Omega \geq C ||v||_{1,q}　\quad (0<C )
$$
Does the constant $C$ equal to $1$?

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure for this problem.
But I felt that you should first prove that
$W^{-1,p}(\Omega)=(W^{1,p}(\Omega))^*$.
But this can follow immediately by definition, definition itself.
If this is the case, then simply use the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: I think you want a $p’$ there (the Holder conjugate)

Comment: I agree with you that $W^{-1,p}(\Omega)=(W^{1,q}(\Omega))^*$, which is from the definition. Then, next, how to continue the proof with Han-Banach theorem. I am sorry that maybe it is too trivial, but I cannot figure out the proof.